# Kotlinx-html ref event

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, kotlin

I've noticed the following function in the code base, which uses [kotlinx html](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.html), and it's pretty hard to fully understand:

```
private fun <E : HTMLElement> Tag.xrefImpl(prop: KMutableProperty0<E?>) = 
    this.consumer.onTagEvent(this, "ref", { prop.set(it.asDynamic()) })
```

As far as I understood from googling, `asDynamic` is a kotlin-js method, that simply suppresses the type checking. OK, but the rest of it is still unclear. [The documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.html/wiki) isn't very detailed about its internals, namely `consumer`, `ref` and `onTagEvent`. On top of that, why is the parameter type `KMutableProperty0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This small piece of code is pretty intense with kotlin idioms and advanced features, so it's better to examine it step by step.

- First of all, `xRefImpl` is an extension function to a `Tag`, so having a `Tag` instance, you'll be able to call this new method.
- Second, `ref` is actually a react property, which allows to get a reference to the component. Here is an example from [react documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Example usage:

```
<input type="text"
       ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }} />
```

By contract, `ref` accepts a function which will be invoked by the engine, with a reference to a component passed as an argument. The code above creates a `ref` on `this` tag (remember `xrefImpl` an extension function) with the following lambda: `prop.set(it.asDynamic())`.

- Next, `prop` is a statically-typed kotlin property (this is what `KMutableProperty0` means). It has `get` and `set` methods, and in this case it's assigned with `it` reference. Since `it` comes from the javascript, its type is unknown, hence [dynamic cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/dynamic-type.html).
- `consumer.onTagEvent()` is just a kotlix-html internal way to bind javascript properties and events.

For example, this is how 'onmouseleave' is processed in this framework:

```
consumer.onTagEvent(this, "onmouseleave") {
  console.log(it)
}
```

If you strip all kotlin and react idioms, the code `this.consumer.onTagEvent(this, "ref", { prop.set(it.asDynamic()) })` simply does `prop = this.getComponent()`. The purpose of the method is, thus, to acquire a component reference.

Finally, since the argument is `KMutableProperty0`, it allows to bind a component to a field, like this.

```
xrefImpl(this::component)
```